# Mixed ListActivity

Tags: android

I want to create a ListActivity that has both checkboxs and single selection groups. Like in the Sound Settins in the "Settings" application of android.

Anyone has link to a sample ?

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at this Android solution we've recently finished as a student project. This source file demonstrates such a settings screen as you've shown here:
[link](http://code.google.com/p/sw6android/source/browse/sw6.schedule/branches/prototype1/src/sw6/visualschedule/adminpanel/ActivityConstructor.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a "settings" Activity you should use the Preferences framework. Check this small [tutorial](http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/integrating-preferences.html): you have to create a special layout and make a reference from code like this:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```